Backups deja-dup application issue
Ubuntu 22.04 Backups (deja-dup)
"waiting for 240 GB drive to connect"
What if I no longer have the USB drive. It won't allow me to backup this machine. I tried uninstalling / reinstalling the app did not help. I deleted any .conf or .cache folders / files I could find. Any tricks to fix this?
Only way I see to fix this is install a fresh copy of Ubuntu 22.04 which is totally out of the question.
What file is hiding this link between deja-dup and 240 GB dive?

turn off auto backups

Thanks, Organic Marble. That did not help. I never found a solution so I decided to dump it. I decided to try Timeshift. Wow! what an amazing and simple app that is.
